# How do I copy datas with blank/tab into multiple excel cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I got a data like:

```
xx5     600     200

xx6     500     100
```

I want to copy them into multiple excel cells, like:

```
--------------------------------------------------
|    xx5   |        600       |      200         |
--------------------------------------------------
|    xx6   |        500       |      100         |
--------------------------------------------------
```

## How to do it?

---

If I paste them directly, I'll got:

```
--------------------------------------------------
|    xx5    600    200        |     |      |     |
--------------------------------------------------
|    xx6    500    100        |     |      |     |
--------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Don't paste.  Use `Data / Import from Text` and then specify how the columns should be interpreted.

Comment: @Paul, that works well. Is this a duplicate question?

Comment: I didn't check, did you see one?

Comment: @Paul, I didn't, but I guess there would be a similar one.